# uncountable open sets and seperability

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How can I prove that a nonseparable metric space consists of uncountable number of open sets which do not intersect with each other?

I am working on metric spaces, countability and separability but I have problem to prove that. I know that a metric space X is separable if it contains a countable and dense subset of X but proving that is a problem for me.

Comment: "a metric space is unseparable if it consists of uncountable number of open sets" this statement is wrong.  R is seperable and it contains an uncountable number of open sets

Comment: Are you trying to prove nonseparable implies uncountably many open sets (true); or uncountably many open sets implies nonseparable (false)--the real numbers with the standard topology is a counterexample.

Comment: okay. i am trying to prove uncountably many open sets implies nonseparable but the open sets do not intersect with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an uncoutable collection $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of disjoint open subsets of a space $X$. By contradiction, assume $X$ is separable. Then, there exists a dense countable set $Q\subset X$. This implies that every open sets intersects $Q$ non-trivially.

In particular, for every $\alpha$ there exists $q_\alpha \in U_\alpha \cap Q$. Since the $U_\alpha$'s are disjoint, $\alpha \ne \beta \Rightarrow q_\alpha \ne q_\beta$. Thus this defines an injection $A \to Q$ which is absurd since $A$ is uncountable and $Q$ is countable.